# How to specify in JRuby that a Ruby class implements several java interfaces

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I know the syntax to specify that a Ruby class implements one java interface in JRuby, but I don't know how to specify if we want the class to implement more than one interface.

What i tried was:

```
class MyClass
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script'
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
```

I also tried:

```
class MyClass
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script', 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
```

But I have an exception when I try to cast the

```
Object o1 = object.toJava(Interface1.class);
Object o2 = object.toJava(ContextListener.class);
```

But strangely for the second interface I have the following exception:

```
rg.jruby.exceptions.TypeError: (TypeError) cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.gen.RubyObject1 to interface org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener
(TypeError) cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.gen.RubyObject1 to interface org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener
```

My ContextListener interface has the following Java code:

```
public void init(ScriptContext context);
```

And my Ruby class is as follows:

```
require 'java'
import 'org.scripthelper.context.ScriptContext'
import 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener'
import 'org.scripthelper.context.DefaultScriptContext'
class ScriptClass
java_implements 'org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener', 'org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script'
    attr_reader :ctx
    def init(context)
       @ctx = context
    end
  def execute()
    return 10
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a plain old include with your interfaces :

```rb
class ScriptClass
  include org.scripthelper.context.ContextListener  
  include org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script

  attr_reader :ctx
  def init(context)
    @ctx = context
  end

  def execute()
    return 10
  end
end
```